# Crystal Reports - Check for specific record in grouped detail records and suppress image in Group Header if present

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

Using Crystal Reports that is bundled with Visual Studio.Net 2003 in old .Net 1.1 app

I have an invoice report with detail records showing each item on the invoice.  The report uses one dataset and Grouping for the detail records rather then a sub report.

Anyway in the main part of the invoice I have an image which needs to be visible if a certain detail record with id "PNP2" is present.

So I imagine that in the Format editor of the image Ole Object, I can write some code against the Suppress method that will do this - I think that somehow I need to loop the detail records to check each value but maybe there is a better way...

Can anyone help?

wing

Comment: Relevant: [Crystal Report Processing Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms314176%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Is the image in the group header or page header?

Comment: The image is in the Group Header in fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming that the image is in the group-header section.

Create a formula:

```
// {@IS_PNP2}
If Not(Isnull({table.id})) And {table.id}="PNP2" Then 1 Else 0
```

Add the following to the image's conditional-suppression logic:

```
Sum({@IS_PNP2},{table.grouped_field})>0
```

Comment: This method saved my hide for choosing one of two group headers based on the presence of particular criterion.  My only addition is noting that sections are objects too so this is a very powerful tool.